# Adding PDF pages depending on element in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I have a need to create a pdf straight from the source of my html page, which is does successfully, but now I need to get the formatting right. What I want, is to be able to add a new page every time a `<p class="form-control-static"></p>` pops up in the source.

I have checked the documentation and some other stack overflow answers but these are all for adding pages when the content is static and you can create it yourself. My content is changing all the time.

I am using jsPDF to achieve all of this. I am aware of the `pdf.addPage()` command yet I am not sure how to add pages depending on a condition. My current code as follows:

```
$('#downloadPDF').click(function () {
    $('#report').width(522);
    $('.img-thumbnail').width(522).height(348);
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')

, source = $('#report')[0]
, specialElementHandlers = {
    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
        return true
    }
}

    margins = {
        top: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 40,
        width: 550
    };

    pdf.fromHTML(         
        source
        , margins.left
        , margins.top
        , {
            'width': margins.width
            , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },
        function (dispose) {
            pdf.save('Job Report - ' + @ViewData["jobid"] + '.pdf');
        },
        margins
      )
});
```

Obviously it has something to do with the `source` variable containing the html or am I mistaken?

Comment: If jsPDF supports CSS, why not just add style="page-break-before:always;" to the element(s) in question? Or in the CSS for that class?

Comment: It appears that page-break-before only applies when you're printing, not creating PDFs.